# Send to multiple URLs based on selection

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I send users to different pages based on information submitted on the form?

I have a multiple choice question with four choices which leads to four outcomes based on the selection. Below is a calculation inserted into the submit button:

```
=if HowManyMilesDoesYourCarHave.contains("25,001-50,000") then "outcome02.html" else "outcome02.html"
```

This works to send users to the one page, but how do I include the other three selections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect users to different pages based on their selection:

1. Add a calculation field to your form labeled "Redirect URL" (or something similar). Its type should be Text, as this field will output a URL or website address.
2. Use the following if/then statement as your calculation:

> =if Choice = "First Choice" then
>   "http://www.mywebsite.com/outcome01.html" else if Choice = "Second
>   Choice" then "http://www.mywebsite.com/outcome02.html" else if Choice
>   = "Third Choice" then "http://www.mywebsite.com/outcome03.html" else if Choice = "Fourth Choice" then
>   "http://www.mywebsite.com/outcome04.html" else ""

Make sure to replace "Choice" with the name of your choice field and "First Choice", "Second Choice", etc. with your choice field options.

3. Find your form's Confirmation Options from the Submission Settings, and insert the calculation field into the Redirect Url section. Now, when a particular choice option is selected, the user will be redirected to a specific page depending on their choice.

Comment: Can I ask for one step further? What is I need two conditions to be true in one "if" statement. As example =if Choice = "First Choice" and "Second Choice" then "http://www.mywebsite.com/outcome01.html"

Comment: If you're testing for two conditions to be true at once, I assume that your Choice field is set to the Checkboxes type. In this case, the expression is slightly different: =if Choice.Contains("First Choice") and Choice.Contains("Second Choice") then "http://www.mywebsite.com/outcome02.html" else if Choice.Contains("First Choice") then "http://www.mywebsite.com/outcome01.html" else ""

Comment: Thanks for responding. Actually one is set as a drop down menu with 5  items and the other is set to a drop down with two items. Will the expression be the same as you wrote above?

Comment: If you're referencing two different Choice fields, the expression would look more like: =if (Choice1 = "First Choice" and Choice2 = "First Choice") then "Website 1" else if (Choice1 = "Second Choice" and Choice2 = "First Choice") then "Website 2" else ""

Comment: My expression returns an error of ')' or operator expected at character 65.

Comment: Sorry... My expression returns an error of ')' or operator expected at character 36.  =if (Mileage = "0-25,000” and CDI = "Yes" and Fuel = “yes") then "outcome01.html” else if (Mileage = "0-25,000" and CDI = "Yes" and Fuel = "No") then "outcome01.html" else ""      What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: All set. Looks like smart quotes were in place of the " " and that was causing an error.

Comment: Help, when pasting script into the Redirect Url field, the following error appears below the field: 
Url must begin with http:// or https://